# Can not convert pandas columns to datetime

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have below code to create date-time object

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as datetime
Dat = pd.DataFrame({'year': [1200, 1400, 1300], 'month': [2,3,4],  'day': [1,2,3]})
datetime.datetime(Dat['year'].astype(int), Dat['month'].astype(int), Dat['day'].astype(int))
```

With this I am getting below error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 141, in wrapper
    raise TypeError(f"cannot convert the series to {converter}")
TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>
```

I am using `pandas` version as `1.2.3`

Can you please help me to understand why am I getting this error? What is the correct code?

Comment: are years correct?

Comment: Why do you think they are incprrect?

Comment: I think `1200`, `1400`, `1300` values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) with selecting columns:

```
Dat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Dat[['year','month','day']])
```

If only 3 column called `year, month, day` in Dataframe solution is simplier:

```
Dat['date'] = pd.to_datetime(Dat)
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to understand why `datetime.datetime` is failing in my code?

Comment: @BrianSmith - because `datetime.datetime` working with scalars, `pd.to_datetime` working with arrays

Comment: Do column names matter? I tried with `Dat = pd.DataFrame({'yr': [1900, 1900, 1900], 'mnt': [2,3,4],  'day': [1,2,3]}); pd.to_datetime(Dat[['yr','mnt','day']])` - this generates error

Comment: @BrianSmith - exactly, need columns names `year, month, day`